# why my GridView is loading very slow in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, performance

I have a grid of 4x3 in Android and it's a calendar application but the problem is it's loading very slow in my tablet.

It's loading after 10sec, my question is how to make it faster ?

Please suggest me some better solution.

Comment: Is it getting data from the Internet?? or all local data??

Comment: There is no database concept in my app , i have simply applied some logic and displaying the values in the grid but the grid is loading after 10 sec...

Comment: Can you show us how you are implementing your `Adapter`?

Comment: add some more info please. code or how ur grid get populated

Comment: Yes this is just about taking a Class extends to BaseAadapter , and putting the object into Gridview ... setAdapter....

Comment: what data u are showing on ur grid ? image ?

Comment: Its better to add code... For better solution

Comment: Give me some time i am posting my code...